# Get PermGen space error on running Jboss 5.1.0 as a service on Windows machine.

Tags: windows-services, jboss5.x, permgen

How do I get PermGen space error on running Jboss 5.1.0 as a service on Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that JBoss is started by `bin\run.bat` file (at least I see something like that in `service.bat` file).

In that case it should be sufficient to edit `run.conf.bat` file and change the `-XX:MaxPermSize` parameter. These parameter allows you to set up perm gen space size.